# Using js variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with this jquery script. I have an a tag that has height:80% and the width is calculated by Javascript. I'm trying to expand it horizontaly with jquery on mouse over, so the width will have to be again calculated by JS. The script I'm using is the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#bmenu1-1").mouseenter(function(){
    var imh=(window.innerHeight||screen.availHeight)*0.18;
    var imw=imh+"px";
        $("#bmenu1-1").animate({width: imw },500);
      });
    });
```

Nothing happens on the page (when I put my mouse over the element) and I've tried putting there a window.alert(imw) but, also, nothing! If anyone has any thoughts....

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the error console say, if anything? And, in this context, a variable is a variable is a variable. There is no distinction between a "js" and "jQuery" variable.

Comment: seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/8TeYn/

Comment: "What does the error console say, if anything?" - sorry but whats that?

Comment: why? because of what I asked?

Comment: @user2033250 use David's jsfiddle, it's your code and is working.  The error console is different in each browser but it shows errors in your JavaScript/JQuery.  As a sidenote JQuery is just a javascript library, when writing Jquery you wrap it in <script type="text/javascript"> this should show you that it is javascript so as Grant said there isn't a difference between Jquery var and javascript var.

Comment: ok thanks for your help, I think I know whats the problem! Cheers